# how to change dataframe row and column in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

There is a data frame with multiple values ​​in one column.

I want to change the rows and columns of this data frame.

like this..

data:
[image]

result:
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: what would be your output if your source sample data had one extra row say `1, D, D2`?

Comment: I think output will contain 12 rows in that case `(1*2*3*2)`.  Am I right?

Comment: yes. You are right. That's just an example, and in practice the values ​​vary widely.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I need to check your output in your case, suppose when two rows `1, D, D2` and `2, A, A1` are added in input

**Old answer** Actually you want to distribute every available value of cols A to D for each id.  So I used a temporary code to calculate the number of rows that have to be generated for each id by `tmp` code first.  Thereafter I gathered values by pivoting wider the data and lastly replicating the list to desired number of times.

Follow it like this..

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#calculate number of rows to generate
tmp <- df %>% group_by(id, type) %>%
  mutate(tmp = n()) %>%
  summarise(tmp = max(tmp)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(tmp = prod(tmp))

#store this value in variable n
n <- tmp$tmp  

#final code
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value, 
                   values_fn = function(x){
                     l <- list(x)
                     list(rep(l[[1]], n/length(l[[1]])))
                   }) %>%
  unnest(-id)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
     id A     B     C     D    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A1    B1    C1    D1   
2     1 A1    B2    C2    D1   
3     1 A1    B1    C3    D1   
4     1 A1    B2    C1    D1   
5     1 A1    B1    C2    D1   
6     1 A1    B2    C3    D1
```

`dput` used

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), type = c("A", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D"), value = c("A1", "B1", "B2", "C1", 
"C2", "C3", "D1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
wide_df <- df %>% group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(row= row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type,values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Comment: Have you checked its output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with `unstack` and `expand.grid` in case order does not matter and `id` is not used:

```
expand.grid(unstack(x[3:2]))
#   A  B  C  D
#1 A1 B1 C1 D1
#2 A1 B2 C1 D1
#3 A1 B1 C2 D1
#4 A1 B2 C2 D1
#5 A1 B1 C3 D1
#6 A1 B2 C3 D1
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(id = 1, type = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D")
              , value = c("A1", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2", "C3", "D1"))
```

Comment: I think this won't work when there's more than 1 id.

Comment: That's why I wrote *and `id` is not used*. In case `id` should be used it would be good to know if then every time all *types* are there or not. But this information is currently not given.

Comment: Agree this.  OP hasn't clarified

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the posted answers didn't get the right results.

So I got the results my way, But I don't know if this is an efficient way.

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1, type = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D")
            , val = c("A1", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2", "C3", "D1"))
tmp <- aggregate(val~id+type, df, toString) 
result_df <- tmp %>%  spread(key = "type", value = "val") %>%
  separate_rows(A, sep=",") %>% separate_rows(B, sep=",") %>% separate_rows(C, sep=",") %>% separate_rows(D, sep=",")
```

result:

[image]

Anyway, thank you all so much!